# Determine org babel session name specified with header-args property

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is it possible to get org babel source block's associated session name when the session name is specified with the `header-args` property of a file or a heading. `(org-babel-get-src-block-info)` returns null because the session keyword is not there. I had a look at `org-babel-execute-src-block` function definition, it looked rather complicated I couldn't make much sense out of it to determine the bit where it finds the process name associated with the source block.

Comment: Check again: `org-babel-get-src-block-info` includes the session (and other) information, whether it comes from a property  or is specified directly in the source block header. `(assq :session (nth 2 (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))` returns `(:session . "foo")` wherever the session is defined.

Comment: That's right. I was actually being stupid. I just had `:session` in the header args, which defaults to `*Python*` that's why I was getting just `(:session)` from the org babel info function.

Comment: Have you restarted your emacs or pressed `C-c C-c` on the `#+PROPERTY` keyword?

Comment: If I give a name to the session it works fine. I just had an empty `:session` with no name, which defaults to `*Python*` in my case, this wasn't being returned by the org-babel function.

Comment: Correct - `org-babel-get-src-block-info` just looks at the buffer to get the info ("lexical" information) . It does not know anything about default values that any particular evaluator decides to use ("dynamic" information).

Comment: Thanks for your replies!